# PHP: Retrieving image creation year of file

Tags: php, html

I have a db having a table with following columns:

```
id image year
```

I am able to get the image name using :

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

I was wondering if there is any php function through which I can retrive the image upload year. Thank you.

Comment: The year it was uploaded?  The year it was taken?  The year copyright was asserted on it?  The year the subject in the photo was born?  Please be more specific!  Some image formats include metadata that MIGHT be accessible in PHP

Comment: @GordonM The year it was created.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: Something like this, I basically am interested only in the year though.
https://imgur.com/a/X88dp5u

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php MIGHT be of some use but only for certain file types and the information is by no means guaranteed to be there or even in a consistent format.  Your best bet is probably going to be to ask the user to provide that information.

Comment: Looks like you're not looking for the "upload date" but the "creation date". If I'm not mistaken maybe you should edit your post so your question is more clear.

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA   Sorry.Done.